# How can I fill this 2D array?

Tags: c++, algorithm

So you are given an n rows and cols 2D array and you have to fill it by this pattern:

```
f(1), f(2), …, f(n-2), f(n-1), f(n);
f(n), f(1), f(2), f(3), …, f(n-1);
f(n-1), f(n), f(1), f(2), f(3), …, f(n-2);
...
`f(2), …, f(n-2), f(n-1), f(n), f(1);`
```

**Example**

Given the `n=6` the matrix would be:

```
1  2  3  4  5  6
6  1  2  3  4  5
5  6  1  2  3  4
4  5  6  1  2  3
3  4  5  6  1  2
2  3  4  5  6  1
```

This is  what I have done so far, it's pretty much nothing, it only solves the problem for the first line.

```
cin>>n;
    for(i=1; i<=n; i++)
    {
        k=1;
        for(j=1; j<=n; j++)
        {
            a[1][j]=k;
            k++;
        }
    }
    for(i=1; i<=n; i++)
    {
        for(j=1; j<=n; j++)
        {
            cout<<a[i][j]<<" ";
        }
        cout<<'\n';
    }
```

Comment: This sounds like a homework assignment that you really want to figure out yourself or wonder if you’re choosing the right education...

Comment: Yea, but I don't have any idea...

Comment: That’s my point...

Comment: Okay OKAY, so if I put my idea in here, at least will anybody help me?......................

Comment: If by "help" you mean write your code for you: No. But if you have a specific question, we might be able to answer.

Comment: using 2D array and for loop(s) ....

Comment: cin>>n;
    for(i=1; i<=n; i++)
    {
        k=1;
        for(j=1; j<=n; j++)
        {
            a[1][j]=k;
            k++;
        }
    }
    for(i=1; i<=n; i++)
    {
        for(j=1; j<=n; j++)
        {
            cout<<a[i][j]<<" ";
        }
        cout<<'\n';
    } This only solves it for the first line

Comment: @AndreiPatan put that as an code into your question ... longer code is no readable as comment and often is truncated i usually add **[Edit1] new code** ... code is intended by 4 spaces (you can use the `{}` button tool in the editor on selected text)

Comment: how about `for (i=0;i<n;i++) for (j=0;j<n;j++)  a[i][j]=(i+1+j)%(n+1);` which is ugly and slow but should work for starters

Comment: Your idea doesn't work

Comment: It only works for the first line

Comment: @Andrew I see the typo now it should be `a[i][j]=(-i+1+j)%(n+1);` but the debug would show you that (not working tells us nothing constructive) anyway you got a bug in the loops as you are accessing from 1 instead of 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You understand the pattern, on each subsequent line the numbers are shifted. What's stopping you expressing that in code? Working this stuff out is the essence of programming.

Here's one solution, there are other ways to do it, but I hope this is the clearest

```
for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 6; ++j)
    {
        int k = j - i; // the trick!! k is shifted by value of i
        if (k < 0) // but k might now be too small, so adjust
            k += 6;
        a[i][j] = k + 1; // arrays start at zero
                         // but you wanted numbers from one, so add one here
    }
}
```

Untested code

Incidentally your code assumed that arrays start at one, they don't, they start at zero, I've fixed that in the code above.

Comment: That's my problem as a "begginer programmer" that I'm still working on :)). I understand the pattern, I know what I have to do, but it's hard for me to express it in code...

Comment: @AndreiPatan Practice helps, that's why you're given these exercises. But so does seeing other people code which is why I posted.

Comment: Thank's a lot!!!